# Drools Decision Table's Flow

Tags: drools

I currently have several decision tables, and I would like them to run in order.

Let's assume I have the following tables:

- Rule1.xlsx
- Rule2.xlsx
- Rule3.xlsx

If I have a transaction "t", I want "t" to first run through all the rules in Rule1.xlsx. Then I want the updated value of "t" to run through all the rules in Rule2.xlsx.

**How would I go about doing this?**

I am looking into the sequential flag and activation groups, but some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ACTIVATION-GROUP rule attribute, writing an entry into the xlsx file up front applies to all rules in the table. Then insert facts and run your session

```
for( String ag: new String[]{"a", "b", "c"} ){
    kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup(ag).setFocus();
    fireAllRules();
}
```